# Add action in controller called "new"

Tags: grails, url-routing

I want to have an URI : `/project/new`

So it is enough to create new action named "new" in ProjectController   .

However , NEW is a keyword in java generally and in groovy specially .

### My question exactly : How to customize mapping between URI and action which cannot named to that name (i.e: new, class ,[others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), contains "-" dash ,...)?

Answer (score 2):

To customize the URL patterns and or mappings look at `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`. There is an entire section of the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings) dedicated to this and it's quite well written.

In your particular case with `new` you could do something like this:

```
// UrlMappings.groovy
"/whatever/new"(controller: 'theControllerName', action:'theNewAction')
```